# How to get different random nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this code that when you guess the right answer it loops back to the same original random choices. I need to be able to choose which one I think has more followers and if its correct loop back with two completely different random choices not the same as the first.

```
import game_data
import random
import art

names = random.choice(game_data.data)
names2 = random.choice(game_data.data)
correct_score = int()

def game(name,names2,correct_score):
    #print(art.logo)
    follower_count = names['follower_count']
    print(f"Compare A: {names['name']}, a {names['description']}, from {names['country']}.")
    #print(art.vs)
    follower_count2 = names2['follower_count']
    print(f"Against B: {names2['name']}, a {names2['description']}, from {names2['country']}.")
    answer = input("Who has more followers 'A' or 'B': ").lower()
    if answer == 'a' and follower_count > follower_count2:
        print("Correct")
        correct_score += 1
        print(correct_score)
        game(name=names,names2=names2,correct_score=correct_score)
    elif answer == 'b' and follower_count2 > follower_count:
        print("Correct")
        correct_score += 1
        print(correct_score)
        game(name=names,names2=names2,correct_score=correct_score)


game(name=names,names2=names2,correct_score=correct_score)
```

Here is a sample of my other files code.

```
data = [
    {
        'name': 'Instagram',
        'follower_count': 346,
        'description': 'Social media platform',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
        'follower_count': 215,
        'description': 'Footballer',
        'country': 'Portugal'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Ariana Grande',
        'follower_count': 183,
        'description': 'Musician and actress',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
    {
        'name': 'Dwayne Johnson',
        'follower_count': 181,
        'description': 'Actor and professional wrestler',
        'country': 'United States'
    },
]
```

Comment: What should happen when the guess is incorrect? And when should the game end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Recursion** like that **requires two things**:

**First**, your algorithm must **have a termination condition**. That is, there must be a way for your function to terminate without calling itself.

**Second**, your algorithm must **pass on a different state (arguments)** to calling itself again, so it can make the decision further down to terminate the recursion. If the state (arguments) stay(s) the same, how can you decide when it's done?

That's it! These are the exact two things you need to consider.

Comment: Thanks I solved this with your answer.

Comment: I'm very happy to hear that!